# Converting date format SQL using convert()

Tags: sql, oracle, select, date-format

I have the date in the format of `yy-mm-dd` and I want to convert it to `dd-mm-yyyy`. I used the following select statement:

```
select  convert(varchar(30), hiredate, 110)
from emp;
```

But, I keep getting an error that there's a missing expression:

```
ORA-00936: missing expression
```

Can someone please guide me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `hiredate`'s data type is `DATE`, then use `to_char` function:

```
select to_char(hiredate, 'dd-mm-yyyy') from emp;
```

If the `hiredate`'s data type is `VARCHAR2` or `CHAR`, convert it to `DATE` by `to_date` then use `to_char`:

```
select to_char(to_date(hiredate, 'yy-mm-dd'), 'dd-mm-yyyy') from emp;
```